# What are the learnable parameters in batch normalization?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

There are four variables in question: gamma, beta, moving average of mean, moving average of variance.

Is it necessary to snapshot the moving averages, and load them in the testing time?

A better question:

For [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634291/2243015) of batch normalization in tensorflow, do I need to transfer the batch-mean and batch-var from training time to testing time? If so, how can I achieve that in tensorflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - for any use of batch normalization, you *train* by normalizing based upon the statistics of the single batch, but then you run inference by using the long-term average of the statistics.

You should save a copy of your mean and variance-holding-variables and restore it when you're doing tests.

There shouldn't be any magic required:  They're just variables that will be saved and restored when you [use the Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/variables/index.html).

In the specific implementation you reference, the [documentation for `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#ExponentialMovingAverage) has a specific example of how to save and restore the moving averages for training and inference, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clarifies a lot.