# How does one do Inference with Batch Normalization with Tensor Flow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was reading [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) on BN and the stack overflow question on [How could I use Batch Normalization in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow) which provides a very useful piece of code to insert a batch normalization block to a Neural Network but does not provides enough guidance on how to actually **use it** during training, inference and when evaluating models.

For example, I would like to track the train error during training and test error to make sure I don't overfit. Its clear that the batch normalization block should be off during test, but when evaluating the error on the training set, should the batch normalization block be turned off too? My main questions are:

1. During inference and error evaluation, should the batch normalization block be turned **off** **regardless** of the data set?
2. Does that mean that the batch normalization block should **only** be on during the **training step** then?

To make it very clear, I will provide an extract (of simplified) code I have been using to run batch normalization with Tensor flow according to what is my understanding of what is the right thing to do:

```
## TRAIN
if phase_train is not None:
    #DO BN
    feed_dict_train = {x:X_train, y_:Y_train, phase_train: False}
    feed_dict_cv = {x:X_cv, y_:Y_cv, phase_train: False}
    feed_dict_test = {x:X_test, y_:Y_test, phase_train: False}
else:
    #Don't do BN
    feed_dict_train = {x:X_train, y_:Y_train}
    feed_dict_cv = {x:X_cv, y_:Y_cv}
    feed_dict_test = {x:X_test, y_:Y_test}

def get_batch_feed(X, Y, M, phase_train):
    mini_batch_indices = np.random.randint(M,size=M)
    Xminibatch =  X[mini_batch_indices,:] # ( M x D^(0) )
    Yminibatch = Y[mini_batch_indices,:] # ( M x D^(L) )
    if phase_train is not None:
        #DO BN
        feed_dict = {x: Xminibatch, y_: Yminibatch, phase_train: True}
    else:
        #Don't do BN
        feed_dict = {x: Xminibatch, y_: Yminibatch}
    return feed_dict

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )
    for iter_step in xrange(steps):
        feed_dict_batch = get_batch_feed(X_train, Y_train, M, phase_train)
        # Collect model statistics
        if iter_step%report_error_freq == 0:
            train_error = sess.run(fetches=l2_loss, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
            cv_error = sess.run(fetches=l2_loss, feed_dict=feed_dict_cv)
            test_error = sess.run(fetches=l2_loss, feed_dict=feed_dict_test)

            do_stuff_with_errors(train_error, cv_error, test_error)
        # Run Train Step
        sess.run(fetches=train_step, feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)
```

and the code I am using to produce batch normalization blocks is:

```
def standard_batch_norm(l, x, n_out, phase_train, scope='BN'):
    """
    Batch normalization on feedforward maps.
    Args:
        x:           Vector
        n_out:       integer, depth of input maps
        phase_train: boolean tf.Varialbe, true indicates training phase
        scope:       string, variable scope
    Return:
        normed:      batch-normalized maps
    """
    with tf.variable_scope(scope+l):
        #beta = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[n_out], dtype=tf.float64 ), name='beta', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64 )
        #gamma = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[n_out],dtype=tf.float64 ), name='gamma', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64 )
        init_beta = tf.constant(0.0, shape=[n_out], dtype=tf.float64)
        init_gamma = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[n_out],dtype=tf.float64)
        beta = tf.get_variable(name='beta'+l, dtype=tf.float64, initializer=init_beta, regularizer=None, trainable=True)
        gamma = tf.get_variable(name='gamma'+l, dtype=tf.float64, initializer=init_gamma, regularizer=None, trainable=True)
        batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0], name='moments')
        ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.5)

        def mean_var_with_update():
            ema_apply_op = ema.apply([batch_mean, batch_var])
            with tf.control_dependencies([ema_apply_op]):
                return tf.identity(batch_mean), tf.identity(batch_var)

        mean, var = tf.cond(phase_train, mean_var_with_update, lambda: (ema.average(batch_mean), ema.average(batch_var)))
        normed = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, mean, var, beta, gamma, 1e-3)
    return normed
```

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why you don't use 'official' batch norm layer: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100

Comment: I haven't inspected deep into this matter yet, but as far as I see from documentation you just use binary parameter is_training in this batch_norm layer, and set it to true only for training phase.

Comment: @MaximHaytovich I wasn't even aware that existed, if you go their API (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#batch_normalization) that BN isn't even mentioned, how did you even find that? I'm shocked nobody said anything about it before.

Comment: @MaximHaytovich I was under the impression that the code provided on the other SO was the only way to use BN in TensorFlow, I guess I was wrong and the SO post is outdated, right?

Comment: well... I googled it :) Most likely it is not mentioned in API since it is included in version which is not released yet or smth like it. But try it out, post the outcome here. I will post this as answer now

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is 'official' batch_norm layer in tensorflow. Try it out:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100

Most likely it is not mentioned in docs since it included in some RC or 'beta' version only.

I haven't inspected deep into this matter yet, but as far as I see from documentation you just use binary parameter is_training in this batch_norm layer, and set it to true only for training phase. Try it out.

UPDATE: Below is the code to load data, build a network with one hidden ReLU layer and L2 normalization and introduce batch normalization for both hidden and out layer. This runs fine and trains fine.

```
# These are all the modules we'll be using later. Make sure you can import them
# before proceeding further.
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle

pickle_file = '/home/maxkhk/Documents/Udacity/DeepLearningCourse/SourceCode/tensorflow/examples/udacity/notMNIST.pickle'

with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
  save = pickle.load(f)
  train_dataset = save['train_dataset']
  train_labels = save['train_labels']
  valid_dataset = save['valid_dataset']
  valid_labels = save['valid_labels']
  test_dataset = save['test_dataset']
  test_labels = save['test_labels']
  del save  # hint to help gc free up memory
  print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
  print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
  print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)

image_size = 28
num_labels = 10

def reformat(dataset, labels):
  dataset = dataset.reshape((-1, image_size * image_size)).astype(np.float32)
  # Map 2 to [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ...], 3 to [0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ...]
  labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  return dataset, labels
train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
valid_dataset, valid_labels = reformat(valid_dataset, valid_labels)
test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)
print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)


def accuracy(predictions, labels):
  return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
          / predictions.shape[0])


#for NeuralNetwork model code is below
#We will use SGD for training to save our time. Code is from Assignment 2
#beta is the new parameter - controls level of regularization.
#Feel free to play with it - the best one I found is 0.001
#notice, we introduce L2 for both biases and weights of all layers

batch_size = 128
beta = 0.001

#building tensorflow graph
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
      # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
  # at run time with a training minibatch.
  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

  #introduce batchnorm
  tf_train_dataset_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(tf_train_dataset)


  #now let's build our new hidden layer
  #that's how many hidden neurons we want
  num_hidden_neurons = 1024
  #its weights
  hidden_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, num_hidden_neurons]))
  hidden_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_hidden_neurons]))

  #now the layer itself. It multiplies data by weights, adds biases
  #and takes ReLU over result
  hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset_bn, hidden_weights) + hidden_biases)

  #adding the batch normalization layerhi()
  hidden_layer_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(hidden_layer)

  #time to go for output linear layer
  #out weights connect hidden neurons to output labels
  #biases are added to output labels  
  out_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden_neurons, num_labels]))  

  out_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))  

  #compute output  
  out_layer = tf.matmul(hidden_layer_bn,out_weights) + out_biases
  #our real output is a softmax of prior result
  #and we also compute its cross-entropy to get our loss
  #Notice - we introduce our L2 here
  loss = (tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    out_layer, tf_train_labels) +
    beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(hidden_weights) +
    beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(hidden_biases) +
    beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(out_weights) +
    beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(out_biases)))

  #now we just minimize this loss to actually train the network
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

  #nice, now let's calculate the predictions on each dataset for evaluating the
  #performance so far
  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(out_layer)
  valid_relu = tf.nn.relu(  tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, hidden_weights) + hidden_biases)
  valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax( tf.matmul(valid_relu, out_weights) + out_biases) 

  test_relu = tf.nn.relu( tf.matmul( tf_test_dataset, hidden_weights) + hidden_biases)
  test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(test_relu, out_weights) + out_biases)



#now is the actual training on the ANN we built
#we will run it for some number of steps and evaluate the progress after 
#every 500 steps

#number of steps we will train our ANN
num_steps = 3001

#actual training
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print("Initialized")
  for step in range(num_steps):
    # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
    # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    # Generate a minibatch.
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
    # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
    # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run(
      [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    if (step % 500 == 0):
      print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
      print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
      print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(
        valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
      print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I will take a look at the official BN. However, if you have time to write an example using it coupled with something actually answering my original question, I'd be happy to give you a bounty :)

Comment: I have provided an answer of how to use "official" way to use BN here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow. If you want to take a look at it there and correct it, it would be awesome. I also provided a bounty there so if you want to provide the correction or your own answer, I am happy to award it to you. :)

Comment: @Pinocchio updated my answer to include full example of neural network building and training

Comment: @Pinocchio also posted same answer to the question you mentioned, since seems like that question is the first one which people will get from google when searching for 'tensorflow batch normalization'