# How does one use the official Batch Normalization layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I was trying to use batch normalization to train my Neural Networks using TensorFlow but it was unclear to me how to use [the official layer implementation of Batch Normalization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100) (note this is different from the one from the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#batch_normalization)).

After some painful digging on the their [github issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1122#issuecomment-231917736) it seems that one needs a `tf.cond` to use it properly and also a 'resue=True' flag so that the BN shift and scale variables are properly reused. After figuring that out I provided a small description of how I believe is the right way to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow/38320613#38320613).

Now I have written a short script to test it (only a single layer and a ReLu, hard to make it smaller than this). However, I am not 100% sure how to test it. Right now my code runs with no error messages but returns `NaNs` unexpectedly. Which lowers my confidence that the code I gave in the other post might be right. Or maybe the network I have is weird. Either way, does someone know whats wrong? Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# download and install the MNIST data automatically
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import batch_norm as batch_norm

def batch_norm_layer(x,train_phase,scope_bn):
    bn_train = batch_norm(x, decay=0.999, center=True, scale=True,
    is_training=True,
    reuse=None, # is this right?
    trainable=True,
    scope=scope_bn)

    bn_inference = batch_norm(x, decay=0.999, center=True, scale=True,
    is_training=False,
    reuse=True, # is this right?
    trainable=True,
    scope=scope_bn)

    z = tf.cond(train_phase, lambda: bn_train, lambda: bn_inference)
    return z

def get_NN_layer(x, input_dim, output_dim, scope, train_phase):
    with tf.name_scope(scope+'vars'):
        W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[input_dim, output_dim], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[output_dim]))
    with tf.name_scope(scope+'Z'):
        z = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
    with tf.name_scope(scope+'BN'):
        if train_phase is not None:
            z = batch_norm_layer(z,train_phase,scope+'BN_unit')
    with tf.name_scope(scope+'A'):
        a = tf.nn.relu(z) # (M x D1) = (M x D) * (D x D1)
    return a

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
# placeholder for data
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
# placeholder that turns BN during training or off during inference
train_phase = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')
# variables for parameters
hiden_units = 25
layer1 = get_NN_layer(x, input_dim=784, output_dim=hiden_units, scope='layer1', train_phase=train_phase)
# create model
W_final = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[hiden_units, 10], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
b_final = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(layer1, W_final) + b_final)

### training
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean( -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]) )
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    steps = 3000
    for iter_step in xrange(steps):
        #feed_dict_batch = get_batch_feed(X_train, Y_train, M, phase_train)
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        # Collect model statistics
        if iter_step%1000 == 0:
            batch_xstrain, batch_xstrain = batch_xs, batch_ys #simualtes train data
            batch_xcv, batch_ycv = mnist.test.next_batch(5000) #simualtes CV data
            batch_xtest, batch_ytest = mnist.test.next_batch(5000) #simualtes test data
            # do inference
            train_error = sess.run(fetches=cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_:batch_ys, train_phase: False})
            cv_error = sess.run(fetches=cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xcv, y_:batch_ycv, train_phase: False})
            test_error = sess.run(fetches=cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xtest, y_:batch_ytest, train_phase: False})

            def do_stuff_with_errors(*args):
                print args
            do_stuff_with_errors(train_error, cv_error, test_error)
        # Run Train Step
        sess.run(fetches=train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_:batch_ys, train_phase: True})
    # list of booleans indicating correct predictions
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    # accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, train_phase: False}))
```

when I run it I get:

```
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
(2.3474066, 2.3498712, 2.3461707)
(0.49414295, 0.88536006, 0.91152304)
(0.51632041, 0.393666, nan)
0.9296
```

it used to be all the last ones were nan and now only a few of them. Is everything fine or am I paranoic?

Comment: Check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow/38325288#38325288. I also had a NaN in loss function sporadically when I initially tried it and there was 2 issues which I addressed: 1) Lowered learning rate 2) Ensured the batch normalization is performed for EACH layer. Meaning I batch normalize input to hidden layer and output of hidden layer.

Comment: If I use something like: with tf.name_scope('batch_norm'), is it still necessary to pass the scope variable to the batch_norm function?

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, the documentation for BatchNorm is not quite easy-to-use/informative, so here is a short recap on how to use simple BatchNorm:

First of all, you define your BatchNorm layer. If you want to use it after an affine/fully-connected layer, you do this (just an example, order can be different/as you desire):

```
...
inputs = tf.matmul(inputs, W) + b
inputs = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs, training=is_training)
inputs = tf.nn.relu(inputs)
...
```

The function `tf.layers.batch_normalization` calls variable-initializers. These are internal-variables and need a special scope to be called, which is in the `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`. As such, you must call your optimizer function as follows (after all layers have been defined!):

```
...
extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
    trainer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer() 
    updateModel = trainer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
...
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization). I know it's a little late to answer your question, but it might help other people coming across BatchNorm problems in tensorflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
training =tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name = 'training')

lr_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [], name='learning_rate')
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = lr).minimize(cost)
```

when defining the layers, you need to use the placeholder 'training'

```
batchNormal_layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(pre_batchNormal_layer, training=training)
```