# How to use Batch Normalization correctly in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I had tried several versions of batch_normalization in tensorflow, but none of them worked! The results were all incorrect when I set batch_size = 1 at inference time.

Version 1: directly use the official version in tensorflow.contrib

```
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.layers import batch_norm
```

use like this:

```
output = lrelu(batch_norm(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), is_training), 0.5, name=scope.name)
```

is_training = True at training time and False at inference time.

Version 2: from [How could I use Batch Normalization in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow/38320613#38320613)

```
def batch_norm_layer(x, train_phase, scope_bn='bn'):
    bn_train = batch_norm(x, decay=0.999, epsilon=1e-3, center=True, scale=True,
            updates_collections=None,
            is_training=True,
            reuse=None, # is this right?
            trainable=True,
            scope=scope_bn)
    bn_inference = batch_norm(x, decay=0.999, epsilon=1e-3, center=True, scale=True,
            updates_collections=None,
            is_training=False,
            reuse=True, # is this right?
            trainable=True,
            scope=scope_bn)
    z = tf.cond(train_phase, lambda: bn_train, lambda: bn_inference)
    return z
```

use like this:

```
output = lrelu(batch_norm_layer(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), is_training), 0.5, name=scope.name)
```

is_training is a placeholder at training time is True and False at inference time.

version 3: from slim https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/ops.py

```
def batch_norm_layer(inputs,
           is_training=True,
           scope='bn'):
  decay=0.999
  epsilon=0.001
  inputs_shape = inputs.get_shape()
  with tf.variable_scope(scope) as t_scope:
    axis = list(range(len(inputs_shape) - 1))
    params_shape = inputs_shape[-1:]
    # Allocate parameters for the beta and gamma of the normalization.
    beta, gamma = None, None
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_initializer(params_shape),
        name='beta',
        trainable=True)
    gamma = tf.Variable(tf.ones_initializer(params_shape),
        name='gamma',
        trainable=True)
    moving_mean = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_initializer(params_shape),
        name='moving_mean',
        trainable=False)
    moving_variance = tf.Variable(tf.ones_initializer(params_shape),
        name='moving_variance',
        trainable=False)
    if is_training:
      # Calculate the moments based on the individual batch.
      mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(inputs, axis)

      update_moving_mean = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
          moving_mean, mean, decay)
      update_moving_variance = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
          moving_variance, variance, decay)
    else:
      # Just use the moving_mean and moving_variance.
      mean = moving_mean
      variance = moving_variance
      # Normalize the activations.
    outputs = tf.nn.batch_normalization(
       inputs, mean, variance, beta, gamma, epsilon)
    outputs.set_shape(inputs.get_shape())
    return outputs
```

use like this:

```
output = lrelu(batch_norm_layer(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), is_training), 0.5, name=scope.name)
```

is_training = True at training time and False at inference time.

version 4: like version3, but add  tf.control_dependencies

```
def batch_norm_layer(inputs,
           decay=0.999,
           center=True,
           scale=True,
           epsilon=0.001,
           moving_vars='moving_vars',
           activation=None,
           is_training=True,
           trainable=True,
           restore=True,
           scope='bn',
           reuse=None):
  inputs_shape = inputs.get_shape()
  with tf.variable_op_scope([inputs], scope, 'BatchNorm', reuse=reuse):
      axis = list(range(len(inputs_shape) - 1))
      params_shape = inputs_shape[-1:]
      # Allocate parameters for the beta and gamma of the normalization.
      beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(params_shape), name='beta')
      gamma = tf.Variable(tf.ones(params_shape), name='gamma')
      # Create moving_mean and moving_variance add them to
      # GraphKeys.MOVING_AVERAGE_VARIABLES collections.
      moving_mean = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(params_shape), name='moving_mean',
            trainable=False)
      moving_variance = tf.Variable(tf.ones(params_shape),   name='moving_variance', 
            trainable=False)
  control_inputs = []
  if is_training:
      # Calculate the moments based on the individual batch.
      mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(inputs, axis)

      update_moving_mean = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
          moving_mean, mean, decay)
      update_moving_variance = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
          moving_variance, variance, decay)
      control_inputs = [update_moving_mean, update_moving_variance]
  else:
      # Just use the moving_mean and moving_variance.
      mean = moving_mean
      variance = moving_variance
  # Normalize the activations. 
  with tf.control_dependencies(control_inputs):
      return tf.nn.batch_normalization(
        inputs, mean, variance, beta, gamma, epsilon)
```

use like this:

```
output = lrelu(batch_norm(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), is_training), 0.5, name=scope.name)
```

is_training = True at training time and False at inference time.

The 4 versions of Batch_normalization are all not correct. So, how to use batch normalization correctly?

Another strange phenomenon is if I set batch_norm_layer to null like this, the inference result are all same.

```
def batch_norm_layer(inputs, is_training):
    return inputs
```

Comment: I am a firm believer in knowing the underlying concept of what I am using. I would recommend you to read the paper about batch normalization to actually understand why and how it helps: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf

Comment: If you say "are all not correct", what do you mean?

Comment: It is mean "all of them were wrong".

Answer (score 8):

I have tested that the following simplified implementation of batch normalization gives the same result as `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` as long as the setting is the same.

```
def initialize_batch_norm(scope, depth):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope) as bnscope:
         gamma = tf.get_variable("gamma", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))
         beta = tf.get_variable("beta", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
         moving_avg = tf.get_variable("moving_avg", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
         moving_var = tf.get_variable("moving_var", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0), trainable=False)
         bnscope.reuse_variables()


def BatchNorm_layer(x, scope, train, epsilon=0.001, decay=.99):
    # Perform a batch normalization after a conv layer or a fc layer
    # gamma: a scale factor
    # beta: an offset
    # epsilon: the variance epsilon - a small float number to avoid dividing by 0
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=True):
        with tf.variable_scope('BatchNorm', reuse=True) as bnscope:
            gamma, beta = tf.get_variable("gamma"), tf.get_variable("beta")
            moving_avg, moving_var = tf.get_variable("moving_avg"), tf.get_variable("moving_var")
            shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
            control_inputs = []
            if train:
                avg, var = tf.nn.moments(x, range(len(shape)-1))
                update_moving_avg = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_avg, avg, decay)
                update_moving_var = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_var, var, decay)
                control_inputs = [update_moving_avg, update_moving_var]
            else:
                avg = moving_avg
                var = moving_var
            with tf.control_dependencies(control_inputs):
                output = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, avg, var, offset=beta, scale=gamma, variance_epsilon=epsilon)
    return output
```

The main tips with using the official implementation of batch normalization in `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` are: (1) set `is_training=True` for training time and `is_training=False` for validation and testing time; (2) set `updates_collections=None` to make sure that `moving_variance` and `moving_mean` are updated in place; (3) be aware and careful with the scope setting; (4) set `decay` to be a smaller value (`decay=0.9` or `decay=0.99`) than default value (default is 0.999) if your dataset is small or your total training updates/steps are not that large.

Comment: Thank you Zhongyu Kuang, I had get the same conclusion with you except item 4.

Comment: I had always problem with `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`. My network converges when I am training but it gives me nonsense results when I test the network and set `is_training=False`. However, the test results when `is_training=True` makes more sense for me (even the accuracy is almost zero in comparison with the network w/o batch_norm). any idea? I asked here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770757/tensorflow-batch-norm-does-not-work-properly-when-testing-is-training-false](Tensorflow batch_norm does not work properly when testing (is_training=False))

Comment: @Zhongyu Kuang can you explain more on the updates_collections . What is we update them with tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS. And how to use them in the inference.

Comment: Hi what about updates_collections=None , Can you please help me understand that . I checked the code what if we use update options ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the Zhongyu Kuang's code really useful, but I stuck on how to dynamically switch between train and test ops, i.e. how to move from a python boolean is_training to a tensorflow boolean placeholder is_training. I need this functionality to be able to test the network on the validation set during the training.

Starting from his code and inspired by [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1122#issuecomment-232535426), I wrote the following code:

```
def batch_norm(x, scope, is_training, epsilon=0.001, decay=0.99):
    """
    Returns a batch normalization layer that automatically switch between train and test phases based on the 
    tensor is_training

    Args:
        x: input tensor
        scope: scope name
        is_training: boolean tensor or variable
        epsilon: epsilon parameter - see batch_norm_layer
        decay: epsilon parameter - see batch_norm_layer

    Returns:
        The correct batch normalization layer based on the value of is_training
    """
    assert isinstance(is_training, (ops.Tensor, variables.Variable)) and is_training.dtype == tf.bool

    return tf.cond(
        is_training,
        lambda: batch_norm_layer(x=x, scope=scope, epsilon=epsilon, decay=decay, is_training=True, reuse=None),
        lambda: batch_norm_layer(x=x, scope=scope, epsilon=epsilon, decay=decay, is_training=False, reuse=True),
    )


def batch_norm_layer(x, scope, is_training, epsilon=0.001, decay=0.99, reuse=None):
    """
    Performs a batch normalization layer

    Args:
        x: input tensor
        scope: scope name
        is_training: python boolean value
        epsilon: the variance epsilon - a small float number to avoid dividing by 0
        decay: the moving average decay

    Returns:
        The ops of a batch normalization layer
    """
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=reuse):
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
        # gamma: a trainable scale factor
        gamma = tf.get_variable("gamma", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0), trainable=True)
        # beta: a trainable shift value
        beta = tf.get_variable("beta", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=True)
        moving_avg = tf.get_variable("moving_avg", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
        moving_var = tf.get_variable("moving_var", shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0), trainable=False)
        if is_training:
            # tf.nn.moments == Calculate the mean and the variance of the tensor x
            avg, var = tf.nn.moments(x, range(len(shape)-1))
            update_moving_avg = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_avg, avg, decay)
            update_moving_var = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_var, var, decay)
            control_inputs = [update_moving_avg, update_moving_var]
        else:
            avg = moving_avg
            var = moving_var
            control_inputs = []
        with tf.control_dependencies(control_inputs):
            output = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, avg, var, offset=beta, scale=gamma, variance_epsilon=epsilon)

    return output
```

Then I use the batch_norm layer in this way:

```
fc1_weights = tf.Variable(...)
fc1 = tf.matmul(x, fc1_weights)
fc1 = batch_norm(fc1, 'fc1_bn', is_training=is_training)
fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
```

Where is_training is a boolean placeholder. Note that the bias addition is not needed because is replaced by the beta parameter as explained in the [Batch Normalization paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).

During execution:

```
# Training phase
sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: bx, y: by, is_training: True})

# Testing phase
sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: bx, y: by, is_training: False})
```

Comment: Notice that you can use tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm() - and that the is_training arg that it accepts may be a boolean placeholder !

Comment: Actually, the question was about a different way to implement the batch normalization in tensorflow, so I provided the code I wrote to implement it without using any function from the contrib module.
Officially, "contrib module contains volatile or experimental code", so it could be useful avoid using it in some scenarios.