# Tensorflow You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype bool

Tags: tensorflow

I run the code for second respondents and catch an error.
[tensorflow batch normalizatioon second respondents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow)
Error pic here

[image]

Comment: Please add your error like as plain text not pic

Answer (score 2):

When you run the op, you must provide a value for `feed_dict`.

Here is an example program:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the inputs you will feed into the tensorflow computation graph
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1], name="a")
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[4], name="x")
# This is the actual computation we want to run.
output = a * x

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Actually run the computation, feeding in [10] for a, and [1, 2, 3, 4] for x.
  # This will print out: [10 20 30 40]
  print sess.run(output, feed_dict={a: [10], x: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```