# How do I use Batch Normalization in a multi-gpu setting in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Referencing this post on [How could I use Batch Normalization in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow).

I have a multi-gpu setup similar to the CIFAR10 example. When I insert tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm to my network definition, I get a NoneType object in average_gradients. Specifically, the `variable g` is the NoneType.

```py
def average_gradients(tower_grads):
    average_grads = []
    for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
        grads = []
        for g, _ in grad_and_vars:
            expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)
            grads.append(expanded_g)
        grad = tf.concat(0, grads)
        grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)
        v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
        grad_and_var = (grad, v)
        average_grads.append(grad_and_var)
    return average_grads
```

Some sample code on how to run Batch Normalization in a multi-gpu environment would help.

EDIT:

Simply removing the "batch_norm" variables solves this bug. However, the pressing question here is that each Batch Normalization has a beta and gamma on each GPU, with their own moving averages. How are all these moving averages over all the GPUs resolved at inference?

Comment: what if you skip all the None grads? (None is mathematically equivalent to 0 gradient). I've use helpers that replace all Nones with 0's at some point

Comment: but what about the gammas and betas? there are unique gammas and betas on each GPU (correct me if I'm wrong on this), and these gammas and betas have to somehow be merged at the end of training?

Comment: there's gamma and beta for each `batch_norm` op, so if you have a batch norm for each GPU, there will be a corresponding pair of gammas and betas

Comment: yeah but how are they resolved during inference? can I assume the contrib layer will handle this?

Comment: I've raised an issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7439). Tensorflow does not seem to have official support for batch normalization yet. Even if they do, it <i>might</i> be optimized heavily for their internal [TPUs](http://www.in.techradar.com/news/computing-components/Googles-Tensor-Processing-Unit-explained-this-is-what-the-future-of-computing-looks-like/articleshow/53818244.cms).

Answer (score 2):

Just use BN independently across GPUs, while using one of the tower means to update the moving mean.

```
with tf.device('..'):
  x,y = iterator.get_next()

  // NN with variables copied over to each of the GPUs
  loss = tower_loss(..)

  // use last tower statistics to update the moving mean/variance 
  batchnorm_updates = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, scope=scope)

apply_gradient_op = average_gradients(*grads)
batchnorm_updates_op = tf.group(*batchnorm_updates)
train_op = tf.group(apply_gradient_op, batchnorm_updates_op)
```

As gleaned from multiple comments [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7439#issuecomment-279193381), this simple asynchronous approach works well in practice for most domains, with the exception of problems like semantic segmentation, action video recognition etc. where the batch size is extremely small and async BN isn't able to afford the speed boost that it normally does.