# How is it that the tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d does not require to update the moving_mean and moving_variance explicitly?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

How is it that the `tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d` layer does not require the user to explicitly update the moving_statistics?

The reason that I am asking is because I recently asked [Why do we need to explicitly update the moving_mean and moving_variance in TensorFlow's Batch normalization in tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927426/why-do-we-need-to-explicitly-update-the-moving-mean-and-moving-variance-in-tenso) trying to figure out how to use `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` without having to explicitly update the moving_statistics.

However, I noticed that there was a different layer [tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/higher_level_ops_for_building_neural_network_layers_#convolution2d) that allows you to provide a normalization layer (say `normalizer_fn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`) but **does not require to explicitly update the moving statistics** (as I detailed on my other question). How is that dark magic happening? i.e. how is the convolution2d able to skip the (what seems) unavoidable requirement?

Ideally, I'd like to create a similar API/interface so that I am not required to update the moving_stats explicitly and work as cleanly as this convolution2d layer.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d` does not know or do anything special about batch normalization or its statistics. If you look at the implementation, all it does is apply a normalizer function of your choice. From [`tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L914):

```
if normalizer_fn is not None:
  normalizer_params = normalizer_params or {}
  outputs = normalizer_fn(outputs, **normalizer_params)
```

So the convolutional layer isn't really related to your question. It's just the implementation of batch normalization that is relevant. For the remaining part of your question, see my answer at:
[Why do we need to explicitly update the moving_mean and moving_variance in TensorFlow's Batch normalization in tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927426/why-do-we-need-to-explicitly-update-the-moving-mean-and-moving-variance-in-tenso)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did read your other answer, but I'm still confused. Even if one builds different graphs, one has to tell the software at some point even if its manually wether batch normalization (BN) should be applied or not. Does that mean that the `tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d` does it wrong and always applies it in inference mode? unless they have it explicitly written I am prety sure one needs the logic `z = tf.cond(train_phase, lambda: bn_train, lambda: bn_inference)` for batch normalization (BN) to work properly. So your answer makes me think `tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d` is buggy.

Comment: The convolution layer unconditionally applies normalization. However, the behavior of batch normalization differs in training and inference modes.

Comment: sorry but I will be super direct. Is the implementation incorrect or not?

Comment: I guess this is the part that I don't get, how does it know if my model is in train or in inference mode? Is it because as you implied in your other answer, models for training and inference are usually separate so one just hard codes this variable to true or false? But it seems one still needs the `tf.cond` somehow. Sorry I just don't know how to by pass that detail. Either they have that part of the code written or I believe the code is incorrect I guess.

Comment: The convolutional layer does *not* know. It unconditionally applies normalization. However, if that normalization is batch normalization, it does different things depending on the value of the `is_training` parameter passed when the layer was built in Python. There are two ways to pass the `is_training` parameter --- either as an explicit Python parameter, or via the argument scope mechanism. The decision is made at graph construction time, not at run time (which is the case where you would need `tf.cond`).