# What does the function control_dependencies do?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to have an example illustrating the use of the function [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies). For example, I want to create two tensors `X` and `Y` and if they are equal do or print something.

```
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.Session()

X = tf.constant(5)
Y = tf.constant(50)

with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assert_equal(X, Y)]):
    print('X and Y are equal!')
```

In the code above, `X` is clearly not equal to `Y`. What is `tf.control_dependencies` doing in this case?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`control_dependencies` is not a conditional. It is a mechanism to add dependencies to whatever ops you create in the `with` block. More specifically, what you specify in the argument to `control_dependencies` is ensured to be evaluated before anything you define in the `with` block.

In your example, you don't add any (TensorFlow) operations in the `with` block, so the block does nothing.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33950177/524436) has an example of how to use `control_dependencies`, where it is used to make sure the assignments happen before the batchnorm operations are evaluated.