# Do we need to declare control_dependencies in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I noticed in **tensorflow**, `control_dependencies` is an important thing and we need to take care of it.
Nonetheless when I implement a model with tensorflow keras, I noticed if I don't add `control_dependencies`, it seems it is still okay.

For instance, let's say I have a model with 4-layers LSTM as follows:

```
import numpy as np

sequence_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(dtype='int32', shape=(3,))
embedding_output = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=100, output_dim=5, input_length=10)(sequence_input)
lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(embedding_output)
lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(lstm_output)
lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(lstm_output)
lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=False)(lstm_output)
output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')(lstm_output)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[sequence_input], outputs=output)
print(model.summary())
sequence_input = np.random.randint(100, size=(5, 3))
print(model.predict([sequence_input]))
```

Here I have 4-lstm layers on top of embedding layers. The output is a normal sigmoid activation. With this I think the implementation of the model is correct.

However, I think I should implement this using control_dependencies as follows:

```
import numpy as np

sequence_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(dtype='int32', shape=(3,))
embedding_output = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=100, output_dim=5, input_length=10)(sequence_input)
lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(embedding_output)
with tf.control_dependencies([lstm_output]):
    lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(lstm_output)
    with tf.control_dependencies([lstm_output]):
        lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(lstm_output)
        with tf.control_dependencies([lstm_output]):
            lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=False)(lstm_output)
            with tf.control_dependencies([lstm_output]):
                output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')(lstm_output)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[sequence_input], outputs=output)
print(model.summary())
sequence_input = np.random.randint(100, size=(5, 3))
print(model.predict([sequence_input]))
```

Nonetheless the code runs OK in two cases, and I think the implementation is correct in two cases as well. 
**Thus, my question is:** Do we need to declare `control_dependencies` in tf keras. Plus if not - Why don't we need to use `control_dependencies` in `tf.keras`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be specific - what you specify in the argument to the  **control_dependencies** is ensured to be **evaluated** before anything you define in the with block.

Please refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095625/what-does-the-function-control-dependencies-do/42095969) to understand more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you misunderstood my question - my point is even if I don't have control_dependencies in the code - it seems works well. Indeed I have never seen a keras tutorial that involves with control_dependencies in creating model.

Comment: because this function is not mandate to run the code rather its a additional functional which - When eager execution is enabled, any callable object in the control_inputs(inputs of control_dependencies ) list will be called. Hence it is good to have but not necessary. Hope that helps you.