# Batch normalization initializer in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, batch normalization parameters include `beta`, `gamma`, `moving mean`, and `moving variance`. However, for initializing these parameters there is only one argument in `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(*args, **kwargs)` called `param_initializers` which according to the documents it contains optional initializers for `beta`, `gamma`, `moving mean` and `moving variance`.

How can we use `param_initializers` to initialize these parameters?

Comment: The parameter initializer is used [here](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L497) and an example use is [here](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers_test.py#L2438).

Comment: Tensorflow 1.0 is released and batch norm layer has moved out of contrib. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you use [batch normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) with Tensorflow 1.0:

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_normalization = tf.layers.batch_normalization

... (define the network)
net = batch_normalization(net)
... (define the network)
```

If you want to set parameters, just do it like this:

```
net = batch_normalization(net, 
                          beta_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), 
                          moving_variance_initializer=tf.ones_initializer())
```

### *args, **kwargs

This is the python way to pass arbitrary many non-keyword arguments `args` and arbitrary many keyword arguments `kwargs`. For example:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print("#" * 80)
    print(args)
    print("#" * 80)
    print(kwargs)

test(1, 2, 42, 3.141, 'foo', a=7, b=3, c='bla')
```

gives

```
################################################################################
(1, 2, 42, 3.141, 'foo')
################################################################################
{'a': 7, 'c': 'bla', 'b': 3}
```