# Difference between tf.nn.batch_normalization and tf.nn.batch_norm_with_global_normalization

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I am trying to implement batch normalization using tensorflow and found this [nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow). Both functions seem to take similar parameters yet it seems like people use the latter more.

Can they be used interchangeably? If not, what are the differences? (And why are there so many similar APIs in tensorflow? Another example would be `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` and `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`. I tried both and they seem to work fine but I feel like maybe I'm missing something subtle here that can drastically change my train results.

Comment: Yeah, it seems there are a lot of redundant function interfaces existing in the official menu. Why don't they keep a clean API?

Answer (score 0):

I guess tf.nn.batch_normalization is better , 
tf.nn.batch_norm_with_global_normalization method is old version and will deprecate later

i think you'll find a better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001759/what-is-right-batch-normalization-function-in-tensorflow/48006315#48006315)