# What is right batch normalization function in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, batch-normalization

In tensorflow 1.4, I found two functions that do batch normalization and they look same:

1. `tf.layers.batch_normalization` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization))
2. `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm))

Which function should I use? Which one is more stable?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just to add to the list, there're several more ways to do batch-norm in tensorflow:

- [`tf.nn.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization) is a low-level op. The caller is responsible to handle `mean` and `variance` tensors themselves.
- [`tf.nn.fused_batch_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/fused_batch_norm) is another low-level op, similar to the previous one. The difference is that it's optimized for 4D input tensors, which is the usual case in convolutional neural networks. `tf.nn.batch_normalization` accepts tensors of any rank greater than 1.
- [`tf.layers.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) is a high-level wrapper over the previous ops. The biggest difference is that it takes care of creating and managing the running mean and variance tensors, and calls a fast fused op when possible. Usually, this should be the **default choice** for you.
- [`tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm) is the early implementation of batch norm, before it's graduated to the core API (i.e., `tf.layers`). The use of it is not recommended because it may be dropped in the future releases.
- [`tf.nn.batch_norm_with_global_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_norm_with_global_normalization) is another deprecated op. Currently, delegates the call to `tf.nn.batch_normalization`, but likely to be dropped in the future.
- Finally, there's also Keras layer [`keras.layers.BatchNormalization`](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/#batchnormalization), which in case of tensorflow backend invokes `tf.nn.batch_normalization`.

Comment: Thanks. i accepted it. I just want to ask you about mean and variance. How can i manage mean and variance as you mentioned? just set is_training flag to False?

Comment: By managing I mean the following: create the variable of the right shape and accumulate running mean/variance from the batches. It's a bit tedious, that's why it's easier to call the high-level function. In that case, you just need to set `training` attribute.

Comment: for future readers, this article nicely describes how to manually manage mean/variance: https://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html

Answer (score 7):

As show in [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib), `tf.contrib` is a contribution module containing volatile or experimental code. When `function` is complete, it will be removed from this module. Now there are two, in order to be compatible with the historical version.

So, the former `tf.layers.batch_normalization` is recommended.