# The difference between tf.layers, tf.contrib, and tf.nn in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

The variants of functions that perform the same functionalities in tensorflow is a very confusing (at least for me). I want to use the official tensorflow API (already gave up on the mess of the high-level API's). However, I trying to understand the difference between tf.layers, tf.contrib, and tf.nn
For example, I am trying to use batch normalization in tensorflow. I google it and the first three links:

[tf.nn.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization)

[tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization)

[tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm)

I understand they both have different parameters and eventually serve the same purpose. But the question is why do we have these three different classes? Is there a valid reason?

I searched the source code and realized that tf.layers is a wrapper for tf.nn

Update: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001759/what-is-right-batch-normalization-function-in-tensorflow).

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006315/712995

Comment: @Maxim, thank you! I didn't find those links you suggested during my search. Closing this question.