# Difference between `tf.nn.batch_normalization` and `tf.layers.batch_normalization`

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

**tensorflow_version : 1.4**

I want to add batch norm to my neural network and I find two `batch_normalizations` methods in TF API.

1. [tf.nn.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization)
2. [tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization)

What's the difference between them and which one should I use in my `n`-layered neural network.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006315/712995)

Comment: @Maxim I will close this. Thanks