# How to select a proper API/implementation of an LSTM cell in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In Tensorflow there are many different implementations of the same task under different APIs. For LSTM cell one can find many implementations, e.g.,

1. [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell#class_lstmcell)
2. [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMBlockCell)
3. [tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTMCell)
4. [tf.keras.layers.LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM)

Which of the above implementation shall I select? Is there a general guideline? For example always use tf.nn > tf.keras > tf.layers > tf. contrib.

In a slightly related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001759/what-is-right-batch-normalization-function-in-tensorflow) (for batch normalization), the approved answer says tf.contrib is not a good choice as it is for early implementation. Therein, the KERAS API also uses tf.nn. So it looks like tf.nn > tf.keras > tf.contrib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here [RNN Performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview#rnn_performance) are some recommendations for TensorFlow. A couple of important points from the doc:

- use `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn()` on NVIDIA GPUs;
- use `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` instead of `tf.nn.static_rnn()`. Probably they mean, that we need to add `sequence_length` to avoid extra computations.