# How to use tf.layers.batch_normalization at test time? How to handle moving variance and mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I am trying to implement batch normalization in tensorflow using tf.layers.batch_normalization. The algorithm works fine for training but doesnt work in testing, I have searched alot on websites but couldn't understand the error, since I am new to tensorflow. I have pasted both the commands which I am using for training and testing, any hint?

```
if is_training: 
   return tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs, axis=0, epsilon=1e-3, scale=True, center=True,training=True)

else:
   return tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs, axis=0, epsilon=1e-3, scale=True, center=True,moving_mean_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), moving_variance_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),training=False)
```

This is the error which I get:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>   uninitialized value batch_normalization_2/beta     [[Node:
>   batch_normalization_2/beta/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@batch_normalization_2/beta"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>      [[Node: ArgMax_2/_3 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_78_ArgMax_2",
>   tensor_type=DT_INT64,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I use Batch Normalization in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949786/how-could-i-use-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow)